# Override ActionBar with custom layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to customize the ActionBar to show a logo. I first tried to do it this way

```
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
```

But I need this to be a bit bigger, so I've tried to create a custom layout and inflate it over the default actionBar.

I've readed several tutorials and almost all matched in the same procedure. So I go on with it:

**custom_actionbar.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ablogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java -> onCreate() method**

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

/*Inflate your custom actionBar layout*/
View customActionBar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBar);
```

But I realize that the custom actionbar layout is not filling the entire actionbar. The logo image that should be at the left side, is at the middle of the actionbar, and it seems like even if the default icon and title are not showing, the actionbar keeps untouchable the space for them.

So, how should be the right way to override the actionbar and be able to set my logo image at the left side of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    //write to this       
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
            getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);


 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nav" />
```

Comment: Neither this way I get it